# Initializing values that point to uninitiated classes. Python @property to control setting of elements within a collection

Tags: python, collections, properties, initialization, getter-setter

My persons class allows a person to have a dict of numbers pointing to friends.
When I make the first person, I can't put any of the persons friends in the persons dict because those friends haven't been instantiated as people yet.

Thus, I initialize all the friends to "None"

However, once a friend has been set, I don't want it to be changed.
When one tries to go bob.friends[2]=john for example, it should throw an error if bob.friends[2]!=None.

Using pythons @property decorator, I know how to control setting of individual variables. However I don't know how to use @property to control setting of elements within an array.
Here are my attempts so far:

```
class person1():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
        self.friends={1:None,2:None,3:None,4:None}

rob=person1('rob')
if rob.friends[1] is None: #I want this check to be done within the class using a property.
    rob.friends[1]="sarah"

#I just want to go: rob.friends[1]="sarah" and get an error if friends[1] isn't None.


#Solution1 was to make my own dict, however I was hoping to instead use @property instead of needing my own dict:
class robs_dict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self,i,j):
        assert(i in self)
        assert(self[i] is None)
        dict.__setitem__(self,i,j)
class person2():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
        self.friends=robs_dict({1:None,2:None,3:None,4:None})

rob=person2('rob')
rob.friends[2]='sarah'
rob.friends[2]='sarah2' #error

#^ solution one achieves what I want, but I want to know if it's possible to use @property instead...


#solution2, unfortunatly isn't scalable if i have many friends..I would have to write many lines of code. Also one could still edit self.friends directly..:
class person3():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
        self.friends={1:None,2:None,3:None,4:None}
    @property
    def friend1(self):
        return self.friends[1]
    @friend1.setter
    def friend1(self,value):
        assert(self.friends[1] is None)
        self.friends[1]=value
    @property
    def friend2(self):
        return self.friends[2]
    @friend2.setter
    def friend2(self,value):
        assert(self.friends[2] is None)
        self.friends[2]=value

rob=person3('rob')
rob.friend1='sarah'
rob.friend1='sarah2' #error

#so basically, i need to improve solution 2 so that I can still use rob.friends as in solution 1, but using properties. is this possible?
```

Any help on how to use properties would be welcome, or any alternative solutions that don't use properties are also welcome. I guess this is common problem, not being able to initialize values at the start because of dependency on other values that haven't been initiated.

Comment: Though this is unrelated to your problem, you should not use `assert` to perform program logic;  The error it raises doesn't really explain the reason the error was raised (`AssertionError` is less informative than the `KeyError` `dict`s normally raise).  Worse than that, in some situations, assert statements are not checked (Specifically, when python is invoked with optimization turned on)

Comment: Why do you think you want to use `@property`?

Comment: If you're going to be accessing the friends through indexing (`blah.friends[x]`), I can't see how using a property is going to help you, because you'd be hitting `__setitem__`/`__getitem__` in the end

Comment: I was wondering if it was possible to somehow use properties without hitting __setitem__. Would you suggest solution1 is the best then? (raising runtime errors instead of asserts)

Comment: it just feels like properties are limited to setting individual items. They can't define how items should be set within a collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `property` Python built-in creates a specialized Attribute of classes - and only that. And what it deos is just to provide explictely a getter (and setter and destroyer) methods to a given attribute.

Since you are intending to customize the access to a dictionary's elements (not `array` Python does not have the losely mixed PHP array figure) - the way to do that is to customize the `__setitem__` method - just as you've made on your "solution 1".

I don't see much of a sense in creating an internal dictionary, and have its keys being numbers (and with indexing starting at 1) to keep track of friends.

What is possible to do, is to create a class that do have N friend_XX attributes, and *do keep* its data in an internal dictionary -
The way to do that, though, is not using `property` - which customizes the access to a single attribute - but rather, you could make use of `__getattribute__` and `__setattr__` which allows you to customize access to any object member that is not explicitly defined otherwise.

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self._friends = {}
    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        if not attr.startswith("friend") or not attr[len("friend"):].isdigit():
            return super(Person, self).__getattribute__(attr)
        index = int(attr[len("friend"):])
        if index in self._friends:
            return self._friends[index]
        return None
    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        if not attr.startswith("friend") or not attr[len("friend"):].isdigit():
            return super(Person, self).__setattr__(attr, value)
        index = int(attr[len("friend"):])
        if index in self._friends:
            raise ValueError("%s already defined for %s " % (attr, self.name))
        if not isinstance(value, Person):
            raise TypeError("Friends have to be persons")
        self._friends[index] = value
```

Using this class at the console you can do:

```
>>> p = Person("Nick")
>>> p2 = Person("Paul")
>>> p.friend1 = p2
>>> p.friend1 = p2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 17, in __setattr__
ValueError: friend1 already defined for Nick 
>>> p.friend1.name
'Paul'
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain the super(Person, self).__setattr__(attr, value). Obviously you can't go self.attr=value.

Comment: The "super" call is an advanced Python concept introduced to properly support multiple inheritance - i t allows one to call a method in a superclass without worrying what is the next superclass to be checked in the inheritance tree. In this case, since we deal with simple inheritance, `Super(Person, self).__setattr__(attr, value)` is just the same as calling `object.__setattr__(self, attr, value)` directly (note that the call to Super uses the "self" parameter itself, while on the "classic" way we have to add it explicitly